# Show and Not show a column in SELECT statement by using WHEN clause or something like this?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a query like below:

I do not want to use where clause. I want to write something in ----- that does not show the A anymore. I think this one is impossible because after then and else we can assign the value to A not remove the A

```
Select
(CASE WHEN A>0 THEN (A) ELSE ----- END),
(CASE WHEN A>0 THEN (A) ELSE ----- END)
from table
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Please _edit_ your question and show us what you have in mind using some sample table data.

Comment: do you need to select multiple columns within case or single column

Comment: @kiarash-moshar I have added an answer below, please check.

Comment: @tim As per my understanding I have answered the question this is what the user probably means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is SQL Server Implementation (Assumption only one column to be removed).** Database [School]

**Table Script**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Matches]
(
    [FootballerName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Goal] [int] NULL,
    [Tournament] [varchar](100) NULL
)
```

**Insert Statement**

```
insert into Matches(FootballerName,Goal,Tournament)
select 'Messi ', 3 ,'La liga' union
select 'Ronaldo ', 5 ,'UEFA' union
select 'Surez ', 2 ,'La liga';
```

**Query for the result (Remove Column Goal from the select statement)**

```
Declare @TableName varchar(100)
SET @TableName='Matches'
Declare @ColumnToRemove varchar(1000)
SET @ColumnToRemove='Goal'

DECLARE @ListOfColumn VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @ListOfColumn = COALESCE(@ListOfColumn + ',', '') + CAST(column_name AS VARCHAR)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName  and table_catalog='School' and Column_Name<>@ColumnToRemove

Declare @Query varchar(1000)
SET @Query ='Select ' + @ListOfColumn +' from ' +@TableName
EXEC(@Query)
```

**Result of the Query (Removing one Column)**

```
FootballerName  Tournament
--------------  ---------------
Messi           La liga
Ronaldo         UEFA
Surez           La liga
```

**Result (With All Column)**

```
FootballerName  Goal    Tournament
--------------  ----    ----------- 
Messi           3       La liga
Ronaldo         5       UEFA
Surez           2       La liga
```

Comment: @kiarash-moshar Please check if this is what's required.